# (C++)Syntax for instantiating and assigning new objects to 2D vector of pointers to same object type?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, 2d

My sincerest apologies if this question has already been asked, but other answers I have seen were confusing to me.  I have a class that I want to use to build a 2D matrix of another type of object.   I'm trying to write a method to create the new objects, and assign pointers in a 2D vector to the new objects, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I create a 2D vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CSinusoid*>> *m_SineMatrix; //2D Vector of pointers to CSinusoid objects
```

And then I try to create a method along these lines:

```
void CWaveMatrix::Init_SineMatrix(int x, int y)
{
    m_SineMatrix[x][y] = new CSinusoid(); 
}
```

The line of code inside the function is where I'm having trouble.  I don't know how to tell a specific pointer in the 2D vector to point to the new object.

Note that both the vector and the method are private members of the same class.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is actually here:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CSinusoid*>> *m_SineMatrix
```

m_SineMatrix isn't a 2D vector of CSinusoid pointers... it's a pointer to such a vector. And the C++ [] operator works on raw pointers just as well as vectors. So the code in your function will call the [x] operator on the pointer and treat the result as a 2D vector, then call the [y] operator on the 2D vector and treat the result as a 1D vector. It doesn't know how to assign a CSinusoid* to a vector of CSinusoid*s, so it complains.

To fix this, you can either change *m_SineMatrix to just m_SineMatrix, or change the function to do (*m_SineMatrix)[x][y].

Answer (score 1):

> The line of code inside the function is where I'm having trouble. I don't know how to tell a specific pointer in the 2D vector to point to the new object.

Your code already does this. The `new` operator creates a new object and immediately points the vector at it.

As a side point, is there any reason that you have a vector of pointers? Vectors already allocate on the heap, so you may just want to put plain objects in the vector and access them that way. Less likely to lead to trouble in the future.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I missed out some key information.  Inside Visual Studio the '=' sign inside the line of code in question is underlined in red.  When I hover above the red line, the message reads: "no operator "=" matches these operands".  Ordinarily anything underlined in red in signifies something isn't correct - are you sure there is nothing wrong with my syntax?

I have a vector of pointers because I did not know what you've just told me.  Good call!

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that m_SineMatrix itself is a pointer! You should try    `(*m_SineMatrix)[i][j]=new CSinusoid()`.

Answer (score 0):

*EDITED*

Okay - it turns out the real problem I had with this is that I wrongfully vizualized the 2D vector as literally being a grid of the object type, when in fact it is a vector OF VECTORS of objects.  In this case, the syntax 'vectorName[0][0] =' access objects directly, wheras 'vectorName[0] =' accesses a vector of the objects, so essentially my code was trying to say 'thisType = thatType' rather than saying 'thisType = thisType'.  It would be like trying to say a bool equals a float, or something like that.  This would explain the red underlined '=' sign.

The following  was a working solution:

```
std::vector<CSinusoid> vTemp; //Create a vector of object<type>
CSinusoid Sine; //Create an object of same type

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    vTemp.push_back(Sine); //Add copies of the object to new vector    //A vector of vectors of objects
std::vector<std::vector<CSinusoid>> m_SineMatrix;
}

for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
    m_SineMatrix.push_back(vTemp); //Add copies of that vector to 2D member vector of objects
}
```